# Unable to open Microsoft Power BI Desktop after installation

Tags: powerbi-desktop

After I am trying to open Power BI Desktop an error message is coming as shown below:

Error Message: AS Process PID=7184 has exited with ExitCode=-1073741511, ExitTime=2021-05-30T08:48:47.9513695+05:30

Comment: This error code is "Entry point not found". You are either running on an unsupported version of Windows (you didn't give any details) or the .NET Framework is broken or missing.